# How to append item into an array inside a struct that's inside a (nested) mapping?

Tags: solidity, arrays, mapping, struct

Very new to Solidity/Coding in general. Trying to make a Kahoot-like game where there's a Teacher (owner) that can upload questions with an ID to each question, 4 optional answers & 1 correct answers.

Created a nested mapping with a Struct in it, and the Struct has an array in it.

How do i append this array inside the struct inside the nested mapping? i tried to do this function but i am getting an error - Undeclared identifier.

Would really appreciate some help!

```
function addQuestion(
uint _qid, 
string memory _question, 
string memory _answerOne, 
string memory _answerTwo, 
string memory _answerThree, 
string memory _answerFour, 
string memory _correctAnswer
) public isOwner {
    questions[_qid][_question] = Questions(Answers.push(_answerOne, _answerTwo, _answerThree, _answerFour), _correctAnswer);

}
```

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract MyContract {
    
    address payable public owner;
    constructor() {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    modifier isOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function deposit() public payable {
        owner.transfer(msg.value);
    }

    struct Questions {
        string[] Answers;
        string correctAnswer;
    }

    struct Students {
        string Name;
        address StudentAddress;
    }
    


    mapping(uint => Questions) public students;
    mapping(uint => mapping(string => Questions)) public questions;

    function addStudent(uint _id, address _studentAddress, string memory _studentName) public isOwner {
        students[_id] = Students(_studentName, _studentAddress);
    }


    function addQuestion(uint _qid, string memory _question, string memory _answerOne, string memory _answerTwo, string memory _answerThree, string memory _answerFour, string memory _correctAnswer) public isOwner {
        questions[_qid][_question] = Questions(Answers.push(_answerOne, _answerTwo, _answerThree, _answerFour), _correctAnswer);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with strings and especially string arrays in solidity might be a little bit tricky. Because in solidity strings are basically byte arrays. If you make a string array, you are making a two-dimensional byte array. Two-dimensional arrays also have some limitations.

Maybe this isn't the ideal solution but this should work:

```
function addQuestion(uint _qid, string memory _question, string memory 
_answerOne, string memory _answerTwo, string memory _answerThree, string memory 
_answerFour, string memory _correctAnswer) public isOwner {
        string[] storage _answers;
        _answers.push(_answerOne);
        _answers.push(_answerTwo);
        _answers.push(_answerThree);
        _answers.push(_answerFour);
        questions[_qid][_question] = Questions(_answers, _correctAnswer);
    }
```